# How do you store settings that get encrypted?

Tags: security, encryption, passwords, cryptography

We have implemented encryption for settings in some of our applications.

The day will come when we forgott the content of these settings. What is a good way to store them? They need to be accessed by certain members of our team.

There is one way I dont like: Our admins use a wiki for this. This wiki is acessible or not. There is no easy way to see what member of the team has information to what kind of logins.

I can think of 2 possibilities:

1. Encrypt them and save them in Subversion. Only members of the team that work on the project have the key to decrypt them.
2. Use an application that is tailored to solve this problem

What is a good way to savely store secrets and make them accessible to certain members?

**EDIT 1**

Here is an example of a problem we might run into:

We have a web application that runs on a webserver. The config has some security critical settings like payment providers. If the system crashes and we have to move the application to a new server we cant use the encrypted config. We have to have one in clear text and encrypt it on the new server.

Its not feasible to recreate the config. We realy have to store parts of it in clear text in a save place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a program that keeps a list of authorized users and only allows them to view certain encrypted files through the program. The authorized users could communicate to the program via a public-key digital signature - in this way the admin could know which users are still authorized, but they would still have to authenticate themselves to access secure data.

But with the example you provide in your edit, I'm a bit confused. That sounds like a slightly different case. You should never store secure data unencrypted, though - that defeats the purpose and security through obscurity is not an acceptable solution! Why not just store the key to decrypt the settings file, so that if it needs to move to other server, you can decrypt it and (if necessary) encrypt it with a new key?

Answer (score 2):

One way you could do this, is to encrypt it with a key, and then give each user 1/2 of the key on a usb drive or some such.  That way they can't *abuse* it and steal the information directly, but would need the cooperation of someone else who has the other part of the key.  And if the usb drive/file is ever stolen, the entire account isn't compromised.  Plus there's redundancy so that if one is lost or stolen you can still gain access and re-encrypt the data.

Comment: Or, better yet, use a [threshold secret sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_sharing) implementation like [ssss](http://point-at-infinity.org/ssss/), which allows you to split the key into *n* parts, of which any *k* are sufficient to reconstruct it.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost passwords **MUST NEVER** be encrypted because this is a vulnerability identified by [CWE-257](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/257.html). Don't forget about the "insider threat"  after all you will have to fire someone eventually.  Also users then to reuse passwords quite often.  In this case i would implement a `sudo` like function where you can assume control over an account.  Or perhaps a simple "forgot password" that most applications have.

If these is a mutual secrets.  For instance randomly generated root passwords that need to be shared,  then encryption is a **good solution**.  Keep in mind that if you fire someone then this secret is compromised,  and you will have to regenerate the secrets.

Comment: For user passwords that's true.  But there are plenty of secrets that need safe-guarding that this would be applicable to (such as the root password for example, or sensitive implementation details).  While I 100% agree for the purpose of user accounts, the fact of the matter is that you need to keep track of certain passwords separately and in a shared manner.  And if that's the case, something like this could be justified...

Comment: @ircmaxell i can see your point,  there does need to be shared secrets.  However don't forget about the "insider threat"  after all you will have to fire someone eventually.  users tend to reuse their passwords but if this is a mutual secret that is unique then this isn't an issue.